Sort function doesn't work and compiler throw an error of "vector subscript out of range"?
I wrote a code for a project about a famous mathematical constant called the constant of Krapekar. Every number that has four digits, being at least two of them different from each other, will be transformed in "6174" in a finite number of operations.
The operations consist of ordering the number in descending order and subtracting from it the same number but in ascending order.
For example, let's take "2349" as an example:
9432-2349=7083; Count=1
8730-0378=8352; Count=2
8532-2358=6174; Count=3

In this case, the input is a list of numbers, for which I have to output the count.
This is my code. I know it has some inefficiencies, because I created more variables than I needed, and I also didn't put conditions to the number, such as not having 4 equal digits.
But my problem is that it has a compiling error that throws
std::Sort_Unchecked:no matching overloaded function found

and the error supposedly appears in the line 8165.
When I tried to run it, despite this, it throws an error of
vector subscript out of range

in the line 1890.
// Constante_de_Krapekar.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int size;
std::vector<int> Numbers(size);
int Number(4);

void display() {
    std::cout << "How many try cases do you wanna set up? \n";
    std::cin >> size;
    std::cout << "Input\n";
    for (auto i : Numbers) {
        std::cin >> i;
        Numbers.push_back(i);
    }
}

int main() {
    display();
    for (auto i : Numbers) {
        int count  = 0;
        Number     = Numbers[i];
        int result = Number;
        while (Number != 6174) {
            int a = result;
            int b = result;
            std::sort(a, a + 3, std::greater<int>());
            std::sort(b, b + 3);
            result = a - b;
            count++;
        }
        std::cout << count << "\n";
    }
}


What do you want to do in this line std::sort(a, a + 3,std::greater<int>()); ? You cannot "sort" an integer. std::sort takes begin and end iterators of a range you want to sort. e.g. std::vector<int> vec({5, 4, 3, 2, 1}); std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());.

int size; std::vector<int> Numbers(size); What is the value of size when it's used to initialise Numbers? Hint: it's not the value you receive from standard input much later.

Mmm oki, after reading closer your description I see that you are looking for a way to "sort the digits" of a 4-digit integer. You can transform int to string, sort it, then transform back. E.g.: int x = 5432; std::string tmp = std::to_string(x); std::sort(tmp.begin(), tmp.end()); x = std::stoi(tmp);

for (auto i : Numbers) { Number = Numbers[i]; What do you think i is?!

Minor: the compiler doesn't throw the error "vector subscript out of range". That's a runtime error.

for ( auto i : Numbers ) { std::cin >> i; Numbers.push_back(i); } ... That's ... not right at all.

If you had a compilation error, you did not run that code but the executable that was the result of your last successful compilation.

The bottom line is that 1) You are not aware of when variables are initialized.  2) You are not aware that you cannot use a range-based for loop and at the same time change what you are iterating over (Numbers), 3) You are calling push_back on a vector that (if item 2) were corrected) is already sized, making the vector have even more elements than 4, and 4) Not familiar with how to use std::sort.  Which issue are you going to tackle first?


Initialization and Declaration of Variables:

std::vector Numbers(size); should be declared after the size is initialized.
int Number(4); is incorrect; it should be a variable, not a function-like declaration.

Vector Initialization and Input Handling:

You need to initialize the vector Numbers after getting the size input.
The loop where you read inputs should not use Numbers.push_back(i) inside the range-based for loop.

Sorting and Calculation:

The std::sort function needs to be used with iterators, and you should handle numbers as strings to get digits in ascending and descending order.

Other Issues:

Ensure that you correctly handle the vector indexing and avoid out-of-range errors.
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

int size;
std::vector<int> Numbers;

void display() {
    std::cout << "How many try cases do you wanna set up? \n";
    std::cin >> size;
    Numbers.resize(size);
    std::cout << "Input\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        std::cin >> Numbers[i];
    }
}

int krapekar(int num) {
    int count = 0;
    while (num != 6174) {
        std::string numStr = std::to_string(num);
        while (numStr.size() < 4) {
            numStr = "0" + numStr; // Pad with leading zeros
        }
    std::string numStrAsc = numStr;
    std::string numStrDesc = numStr;
    
    std::sort(numStrAsc.begin(), numStrAsc.end()); // Ascending order
    std::sort(numStrDesc.begin(), numStrDesc.end(), std::greater<char>()); // Descending order
    
    int a = std::stoi(numStrDesc);
    int b = std::stoi(numStrAsc);
    num = a - b;
    
    count++;
    
    if (num == 0) {
        return -1; // Indicates that 6174 is not reachable
    }
}
return count;
}

int main() {
    display();
    for (const auto& num : Numbers) {
        int result = krapekar(num);
        if (result == -1) {
            std::cout << "Not reachable\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << result << "\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


Thank you all for your comments. I solved the problems
